# How can I store the values of the variables in the class?

Tags: python

```
class Player():
    money = 0
    level = 0
    xp = 0
    xp_until_level = 20
    taxi_car = "Cabbie"
    busines = "No"
    busines_income = 1000
    upgrade_cost = 10000
    car_speed = 10
    car_level = 0
    drives_until_new_car = 20


p = Player()
```

**I need the value of these variables to be saved and loaded when entering the game**
**i tried to use picklе library
but nothing happened**

Comment: How did `pickle` not work?  Are you writing to and reading from a file?

Comment: You have to save the data somewhere. In python you can read/write from your local filesystem with the `open()` function.

Comment: Pickle should work, so you must not have done it correctly. Show what you tried.

Comment: `pickle` saves the values of *instance attributes* - but everything here is a *class attribute*.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @jasonharper um,how can i store instance attributes?

Comment: guys i am trying to save but getting this error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'money' i am saving this way
 f = open("saved_data.bin", "wb")
            pickle.dump(p, f)
            f.close()
and loading
f = open("saved_data.bin", "rb")
      p = pickle.load(f)

      f.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the Values to be associated with the instance Player, the easiest way is as follows:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.money = 0
        self.level = 0
        self.xp = 0
        self.xp_until_level = 20
        self.taxi_car = "Cabbie"
        self.busines = "No"
        self.busines_income = 1000
        self.upgrade_cost = 10000
        self.car_speed = 10
        self.car_level = 0
        self.drives_until_new_car = 20
```

Then instantiate the Player by

```
p = Player()
```

and access the values by:

```
p.money
p.level
```

etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question of persisting `Player` between runs of the script.